# Reading a file using pread

Tags: c, algorithm

The aim of the problem is to use only pread to read a file with the intergers.

I am trying to device a generic solution where I can read intergers of any length, but I think there must be a better solution from my current algorithm.

For the sake of explanation and to guide the algorithm, here is a sample input file. I have explicitly added `\r\n` to show that they exist in the file.

Input file:

```
23456\r\n
134\r\n
1\r\n
345678\r\n
```

Algorithm

```
1. Read a byte from the file 
2. Check if it is number i.e '0' <= byte <= '9'
3.1 if yes, increment the offset and read the next byte
3.2 if not, is it \r 
3.2.1 if yes, read the next and it should be \n. 
Here the line is finished and we can use strtol to convert string to int.
3.2.2 // Error condition
```

I'm required to make this algorithm because if found out that pread reads the files as string and just pust the requested number of bytes in the provided buffer.

Question:
Is there an better way of reading intergers from the file using pread() instead of parsing each byte to determine the end-of-string and then converting to interget?

Comment: A byte is not a number (or is one between 0 and 255 included). It could encode a *digit*. In 2021 [UTF-8 is used everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/). And **StackOverflow is not a do-my-homework website**. See also [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). At last, for efficiency, you need to do some buffered IO. Please provide some [mre] in your question

Comment: You have not actually asked a question.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the description to include explicit question.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am not asking to do my homework. All I am trying to see if there is a better solution or method for such a scenario. Based on my comments, I would be clear that I have a working solution, but I want to improve and thus seeking collective wisdom.

Comment: Also,  [pread(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pread.2.html) is not in standard C (read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or newer). It is on Linux. I guess your teacher expects you to code some *buffered* input. Read the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...)

Comment: This step: "if yes, increment the offset and read the val again" sounds strange to me... how can you read the value again from another offset? And why read the same value twice? You already have the value in memory.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I guess so. In that regards, I guess I am on the right track where I buffer the input from the text file for processing before spitting out the final output as interger.

Comment: If you really need to read [bignums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) - e.g. integers with thousands of digits - you may want to use libraries like [GMPlib](https://gmplib.org/) at least if you need to do arithmetic on them. That library is open source, you are allowed to download its source code and study it and improve it

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an better way of reading intergers from the file using pread() instead of parsing each byte to determine the end-of-string and then converting to interget?

Yes, read big chunks of data into memory and then do the parsing on the memory. Use a big buffer (i.e. depending on system memory). On a mordern system where giga-bytes of memory is available, you can go for a buffer in the mega byte range. I would probably start out with a 1 or 2mega byte buffer and see how it performs.

This will be much more efficient that byte-by-byte reads.

note: your code needs to handle situations where a chunk from the file stops in the middle of an integer. That adds a little complexity to code but it's not that difficult to handle.

> where I can read intergers of any length

Well, if you actually mean integers greater than the largest integer of your system, it's much more complicated. Standard functions like `strtol` can't be used. Further, you'll need to define your own way of storing these values. Alternatively, you can fetch a public library that can handle such values.

Comment: No, a huge buffer of several gigabytes don't help. By experience, megabyte sized buffers are better in 2021. If performance matters to the µs, consider using [readahead(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readahead.2.html) and/or [posix_fadvise(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch well, ok, maybe my wording was bad. Actually I already updated the answer.